# How to take data from gps then send to my phone in arduino

Tags: arduino

I want to do project which will use GPS & GSM module, use Arduino, take data from `GPS(GY-GPS/NEO6MV2)` and send by `GSM(SIM900 GSM/GPRS Module )` to my phone. I am using separate GPS module
I try this code but still have problem.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include "SIM900.h"
#include <TinyGPS.h>
#include "sms.h"
SMSGSM sms;
TinyGPS gps;
SoftwareSerial ss(4, 3);
SoftwareSerial SIM900(7, 8);
static void smartdelay(unsigned long ms);
static void print_float(float val, float invalid, int len, int prec);
static void print_int(unsigned long val, unsigned long invalid, int len);
static void print_date(TinyGPS &gps);
static void print_str(const char *str, int len);
String strL, strN, message, textForSMS;
char charL[10], charN[10], text[200];
int m = 1;
boolean started = false;
void setup()
{
Serial.begin(9600);
ss.begin(9600);
  gsm.begin(9600);
}
void loop()
{
  float flat, flon;
  unsigned long age, date, time, chars = 0;
  unsigned short sentences = 0, failed = 0;
  gps.f_get_position(&flat, &flon, &age);
  textForSMS = "Moosa Home"; //testing gps from here
  Serial.println(textForSMS);
  Serial.println(flat, 6);
  Serial.println(flon, 6);
  Serial.print("longitude: ");
  print_float(flat, TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE, 10, 6);
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("latitude : ");
  print_float(flon, TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE, 10, 6);
  smartdelay(1000);
  Serial.println(""); //till here
  delay(1000);
  if (m == 5) //send sms on third reading
    {
    Serial.println("XXXXXXXXX"); //to check whether 'if' works
    dtostrf(flat, 4, 6, charL);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
  strL += charL[i];
}
dtostrf(flon, 4, 6, charN);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  strN += charN[i];
}
message = "Home";
message = message + "/nLat: ";
message = message + strL;
message = message + "/nLon: ";
message = message + strN;
message.toCharArray(text, 250);
Serial.println(text);

if (sms.SendSMS("+999999999999999", text))
{
  Serial.println("\nSMS sent OK.");
}
else
{
  Serial.println("\nError sending SMS.");
}
do {} while (1);
}
m++;
}
static void smartdelay(unsigned long ms)
{
  unsigned long start = millis();
  do
  {
    while (ss.available())
  gps.encode(ss.read());
  } while (millis() - start < ms);
}
static void print_float(float val, float invalid, int len, int prec)
{
  if (val == invalid)
  {
    while (len-- > 1)
  Serial.print('*');
    Serial.print(' ');
  }
  else
  {
Serial.print(val, prec);
int vi = abs( val);
int flen = prec + (val < 0.0 ? 2 : 1); // . and -
flen += vi >= 1000 ? 4 : vi >= 100 ? 3 : vi >= 10 ? 2 : 1;
for (int i = flen; i < len; ++i)
  Serial.print(' ');
  }
  smartdelay(0);
}
static void print_str(const char *str, int len)
{
  int slen = strlen(str);
  for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
Serial.print(i < slen ? str[i] : ' ');
  smartdelay(0);
}
```

---

I receive SMS

```
Home/nLat:1000.00000/nLon:1000.00000`
```

where is my mistake in this code? 
 I am sure Gps & gsm work properly

Answer (score 0):

Using TinyGPS on `SoftwareSerial` + a `loop()` structure using `delay(1000)`, has very low odds of working.  The `m` counter is really useless here, because `loop()` will execute 1000's of times while the GPS characters are arriving.  And doing a `get_position` is useless, because you may not have any GPS data yet.

Basically, `loop()` should be constantly running, without delays.  When something important happens (like getting *all* of a GPS sentence, or enough time has passed), that's when you do your other work (like send an SMS message).  The TinyGPS `smartDelay` is not smart.

You should restructure the loop to look more like [this example](https://github.com/SlashDevin/NeoGPS/blob/master/examples/NMEAblink/NMEAblink.ino) from the [NeoGPS](https://github.com/SlashDevin/NeoGPS) library.  All the non-GPS work should be performed where the `digitalWrite` is in that example (line 62).  That's where you would take the time to send an SMS.

The TinyGPS examples would require a complete rewrite to do what you want.  They are fine by themselves, but it is difficult to extend them to do other things, like send an SMS.  As I said, the loop structure must change.

I suggest taking a look at the NeoGPS library I wrote, as the examples are more robust.  The library also uses much less RAM and CPU time, but that isn't a big problem if all you need to do is send an SMS message.  If you do want to try it, be sure to review the default `SoftwareSerial` choice.

If you get the simple NMEAblink.ino example to work, I would suggest trying NMEA.ino.  Then insert your code into the `doSomeWork` function.  Most of what you have in `loop` needs to go in the `doSomeWork` function, which is called *only* when a complete RMC sentence is received.

Regardless of which library you use, you also need to check whether the data is valid.  What if your GPS isn't receiving any satellites?  It may still send an RMC sentence, but there won't be any lat/lon data.  You probably shouldn't send an SMS if the location field is not valid.